# Nested JQuery animation with complete, time settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following animation setup in JQuery, I want the opacity to slowly climb to 100% in 4 seconds and there after fall back to 0% quickly. The result i see is the opposite, fast opacity up, and slow fade. What Is my mistake?

```
    $(motorProtectionElementWarning).animate({
        opacity:1,
        duration: 4000
    },{
        complete: function(){ $(motorProtectionElementWarning).animate({opacity:0},1000);}
    },5000);
```

Comment: What is supposed to do `5000` ? Check your syntax, duration should not be put in animated properties object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a shot with this syntax :

```
 $(motorProtectionElementWarning).animate({
    opacity:1,
 }, 4000, function(){
    $(motorProtectionElementWarning).animate({opacity:0},1000);
 });
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Yup extra 5k at the end

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code and its worked.

```
  $(".test").animate({
      opacity:0,
      duration: 10000
  },{
      complete: function(){
      $(".test").animate({opacity:1},5000);}
  },5000);
```

test it : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/m75YU/